# How to add quantity dropdown in cart for configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart, configurable-product

Hello
I am using magento 1.7.0.2 CE. I need to display a dropdown for product quantity to allow a user to select quantity from the dropdown on cart page. I have added a code in `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` for the same which is,

```
<?php echo $min_sale_qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($this->getProduct())->getData('min_sale_qty');
 $total_qyt = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($this->getProduct())->getQty();
     ?>
    <select name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]">
    <?php for($i = $min_sale_qty; $i <= $total_qyt; $i = $i + $min_sale_qty)
      {
      ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i?>" <?php echo ($i == $this->getQty())? "selected=selected": ""; ?>>
      <?php echo $i?>
    </option>
   <?php }?> 
   </select>
```

This code displays the dropdown correctly for simple products. But when I add configurable product to my cart, It displays me dropdown without any option to select.
Can anyone help me with it? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the configurable product does not have minimum sale qty and a total qty.
You need to get the simple product that is represented by the configurable product and get the values from it.  Try this:

```
$simpleProduct = null;
foreach ($_item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $simpleItem){
   if ($simpleItem->getParentId() == $_item->getId()){
       $simpleProduct = $simpleItem->getProduct();
       break;
   }
}
if ($simpleProduct){
   //work your magic with $simpleProduct
}
```

I didn't test, but it seams like the way to go.
I've tested and this works for me. I was close. Instead of `getParentId()` it should be `getParentItemId()`. Here is the code from my `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` file:

```
$simpleProduct = $this->getProduct();
if ($this->getProduct()->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
    foreach ($_item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $simpleItem){
        if ($simpleItem->getParentItemId() == $_item->getId()){
            $simpleProduct = $simpleItem->getProduct();
            break;
        }
    }
}
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($simpleProduct);
$min_sale_qty = (int)$stockItem->getData('min_sale_qty');
$total_qyt = (int)$stockItem->getQty();

?>
<select name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]">
    <?php for($i = $min_sale_qty; $i <= $total_qyt; $i = $i + $min_sale_qty) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $i?>" <?php echo ($i == $this->getQty())? "selected=selected": ""; ?>>
            <?php echo $i?>
        </option>
    <?php endfor;?>
</select>
```

I'm almost sure that there is an other way of getting the simple product and avoid the `foreach` loop but this will do for now.

Comment: Hi Marius. I have tried as per your suggestion but the code is not working. $simpleItem->getParentId() doesn't return anything. And I don't understand why you added if ($simpleItem->getParentId() == $_item->getId()) condition.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Like I said. This was of the top of my head. It seamed like the way to go. I will test and get back to you on this.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya. See my edit.

Comment: due to getModel being called for every item, this script uses a lot of resources when there's around 10+ different products in cart